# How to find how much data usage is required if a specific url is given

Tags: javascript, html, mern

I'm creating a web, to calculate how much data usage is required if a specific url is entered in a form. I know to how to create a form, but I couldn't find any resources to look for internet required a given url. Is there any API for it, please help me out!

I tried refering to website like

1. [How to calculate mobile and wifi data usage of each application in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184510/how-to-calculate-mobile-and-wifi-data-usage-of-each-application-in-android) - which is android specific
2. [How to calculate bandwidth usage for Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230501/how-to-calculate-bandwidth-usage-for-javascript) - didn't get what I expected.

What I expect is, to get how much mega bytes of data is required to load this url. Is it possible to calculate?

Answer (score 0):

Use fetch api and blob method to get size.
Tested in nodejs.
In browser, test with same origin url otherwise CORS error will throw.

```
fetch("https://stackoverflow.com/")
    .then((response) => response.ok && response.blob())
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data.size) //in byte
        console.log(data.size *  1000) //in kilo byte
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Does this account for any scripts or extra content the site pulls?